# Java Script Error Message When I start up the computer

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just bought a new computer, Win10.

Every time after the computer turned on I get the next Javascript error message[image]:

What should I do with that?

Thanks!

Comment: The following link talking about how to fix the ‘A JavaScript Error Occurred in the Main Process’ Error in Discord, you could have a look:https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-a-javascript-error-occurred-in-the-main-process-error-in-discord/

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the mentions of `Discord` in the error message you should try uninstalling or reinstalling the `Discord` application.